# Position and potential Energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, commutator

Why are the position and potential energy of a particle able to be measured precisely in Quantum Mechanics? I mean why do they commute with each other?

Comment: I would guess it is because we assume the potential in Shrodinger's equation to be a function of position, as it is true for conservative forces. 
I do not know QM well, so let's wait for a real answer, but that's my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, if the potential energy is a function only of the position, if you measure the position precisely, you can just calculate the potential energy using that precise measurement. More  formally, if $V(\hat x)$ is any  function of $\hat x$, the position operator $$[V(\hat x), \hat x] = 0$$
which really is just that any operator commutes with itself.